# SQL Server Enterprise Manager 2005 with sqlserver 2005 express

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is it possible to use Enterprise Manager 2005  with sqlserver 2005 express?
I want to use full text creation wizards that available only in Enterprise Manager, with  sqlserver 2005 express.

Comment: There is no "Enterprise Manager" for SQL Server 2005 - it's now called "SQL Server Management Studio". Is that what you're looking for? As "gbn" already mention - you can easily administer a SQL Express database from regular SSMS - but there's also a lightweight "SQL Server Management Studio Express" version.

Comment: I am talking about the one that has wizards for full text search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Express is just a cut down version of the database engine.

Comment: Is there a free stand alone version or it only comes with server 2005?

Comment: Yes.Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express Service Pack 2: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6053C6F8-82C8-479C-B25B-9ACA13141C9E&displaylang=en

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, I asked  for Enterprise Manager 2005.

Comment: @lupital: you have to have a server/developer version of SQL Server 2005 to get the standard SSMS. Mitch is correct otherwise

Comment: @lupital: No. Only Express is free and the Express tools. However, it is not licensed and you should be able to get the tools from a trial version of SQL Server